# Firefox add-on: getting started - how to block url on a certain page?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

I'm trying to develop an add-on to block a list of urls (facebook, twitter, etc.) on a certain website (e.g. mydomain.com).

I'd also like to block ads... Do you know if it's possible to extend adblock plus?

Where should I start? I can't find much info on google.

Many thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual approach would be to [create an XPCOM component](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCOMUtils.jsm) (*note*: the examples are outdated, you have to consider [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCOM/XPCOM_changes_in_Gecko_2.0#JavaScript_components) as well) implementing [`nsIContentPolicy` interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIContentPolicy) and register it in the `content-policy` category. The component's `shouldLoad()` method will be called for each load attempt - you can look at `aContentLocation` and `aRequestOrigin` parameters to decide whether you want to block the requests.

Same is possible with Adblock Plus filters of course, e.g. to block Facebook on mydomain.com you use this filter:

```
||facebook.com^$domain=mydomain.com
```

Adblock Plus [allows other extensions to communicate with it](https://adblockplus.org/en/IAdblockPlus). To add a bunch of filters your extension would do the following on startup:

```js
var filters = [
                "||facebook.com^$domain=mydomain.com",
                "||twitter.com^$domain=mydomain.com"
              ];
AdblockPlus.updateExternalSubscription("FooExtension",
                                       "Filters from Foo Extension",
                                       filters);
```

Comment: Really useful info. Many thanks. I'll give that a try. Currently, I'm just following https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL_School/Intercepting_Page_Loads#page-files

Comment: Do I have to do a `var AdblockPlus=require('AdblockPlus')`?

Comment: @Eamorr: No, the Adblock Plus documentation I linked to explains how you access the API. If you are using the Add-on SDK then you will also need [chrome authority](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.5/dev-guide/module-development/chrome.html).

Comment: Really struggling with this here... I've figured out how to do a chrome authority import (`var {Cc, Ci,Cu,Cr,Cm} = require("chrome");`), but how to view the api and start blocking urls?

Comment: @Eamorr: `if ("@adblockplus.org/abp/public;1" in Cc) { var abpURL = Cc["@adblockplus.org/abp/public;1"].getService(Ci.nsIURI); AdblockPlus = Cu.import(abpURL.spec, null).AdblockPlus; }`

Comment: Greetings, it's all working very nicely now. You've been such a great help! ONe more question - can I package AdBlockPlus inside my addon or does the user *have* to download both addons?

Comment: You've really been a great help today. It's quite hard to google this stuff cos keywords like "addon" and "Firefox" are dominated by non-codey sites.

Comment: Is there an example of the former approach, using nsiContentPolicy to access 'shouldLoad'? Would be a big help, as the ABP interface only provides a few functions, mostly dealing with subscriptions (https://adblockplus.org/en/IAdblockPlus). Thanks

Comment: @rednoyz: The question here was about extending Adblock Plus. On the topic on `nsIContentPolicy` see http://stackoverflow.com/a/10788836/785541.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I did see that post, and I am talking about AdBlock-Plus (ABP). What I'm attempting is to have my addon's version of shouldLoad() called instead of ABP's version. Then, depending on the arguments, I call the ABP version of shouldLoad() myself.

But maybe I should post this as a separate question?

Comment: @rednoyz: Yes, you probably want to create a new question - and explain what you are trying to achieve and why (you seem to be heading in the wrong direction).