# An example of nsIContentPolicy for firefox addon?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

I have read [NsIContentPolicy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/NsIContentPolicy) and have searched whole Stackoverflow for a proper tutorial for implementing NsIContentPolicy, but all in vain.  I know that Adblock uses NsIContentPolicy as their main weapon. Reverse engineering Adblock didn't help me to understand how to implement NsIContentPolicy. Is there any simple addon using NsIContentPolicy for learning, or any good tutorial on NsIContentPolicy?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I am not aware of any good tutorial but I can give you some minimal example code:

```js
Cu.import("resource://gre/modules/XPCOMUtils.jsm");
Cu.import("resource://gre/modules/Services.jsm");

let policy =
{
  classDescription: "Test content policy",
  classID: Components.ID("{12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789abc}"),
  contractID: "@adblockplus.org/test-policy;1",
  xpcom_categories: ["content-policy"],

  init: function()
  {
    let registrar = Components.manager.QueryInterface(Ci.nsIComponentRegistrar);
    registrar.registerFactory(this.classID, this.classDescription, this.contractID, this);

    let catMan = Cc["@mozilla.org/categorymanager;1"].getService(Ci.nsICategoryManager);
    for each (let category in this.xpcom_categories)
      catMan.addCategoryEntry(category, this.contractID, this.contractID, false, true);

    onShutdown.add((function()
    {
      for each (let category in this.xpcom_categories)
        catMan.deleteCategoryEntry(category, this.contractID, false);

      // This needs to run asynchronously, see bug 753687
      Services.tm.currentThread.dispatch(function()
      {
        registrar.unregisterFactory(this.classID, this);
      }.bind(this), Ci.nsIEventTarget.DISPATCH_NORMAL);
    }).bind(this));
  },

  // nsIContentPolicy interface implementation
  shouldLoad: function(contentType, contentLocation, requestOrigin, node, mimeTypeGuess, extra)
  {
    dump("shouldLoad: " + contentType + " " +
                          (contentLocation ? contentLocation.spec : "null") + " " +
                          (requestOrigin ? requestOrigin.spec : "null") + " " +
                          node + " " +
                          mimeTypeGuess + "\n");
    return Ci.nsIContentPolicy.ACCEPT;
  },

  shouldProcess: function(contentType, contentLocation, requestOrigin, node, mimeTypeGuess, extra)
  {
    dump("shouldProcess: " + contentType + " " +
                            (contentLocation ? contentLocation.spec : "null") + " " +
                            (requestOrigin ? requestOrigin.spec : "null") + " " +
                            node + " " +
                            mimeTypeGuess + "\n");
    return Ci.nsIContentPolicy.ACCEPT;
  },

  // nsIFactory interface implementation
  createInstance: function(outer, iid)
  {
    if (outer)
      throw Cr.NS_ERROR_NO_AGGREGATION;
    return this.QueryInterface(iid);
  },

  // nsISupports interface implementation
  QueryInterface: XPCOMUtils.generateQI([Ci.nsIContentPolicy, Ci.nsIFactory])
};

policy.init();
```

This comes from the minimal content policy implementation I use to look at issues with the content policies implementation - it doesn't do anything other than dumping all content policies calls to the console ([`window.dump` documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.dump)). Obviously, in a real implementation the fields `classDescription` , `classID` and `contractID` should be changed to something proper. `onShutdown` belongs to the private framework I am using: this extension is restartless which is why it needs to register the component "manually" and will also run this code to remove it if it is shut down during a browser session.

You can also download the complete extension: [testpolicy.xpi](https://palant.de/trash/testpolicy.xpi).

Comment: Wladimir, that testpolicy.xpi is exactly what i was looking for :) Thanks a lot :)

Comment: example link is broken, <s>imports needs to be updated,</s> but still, this block only network content, and how about altering dom tree?

Comment: @msangel: I updated the link. The code here is merely an example from a simple bootstrapped extension - if your extension is SDK-based then you are free to adjust it so that it works for you but please don't edit the post. The question is about content policies which are only useful for blocking network requests, DOM modifications have to happen by other means.