# How to change script location on firefox addon?

Tags: javascript, firefox, browser, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

What is the simplest way to make the firefox addon, which repeats this chrome functionality:

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
  function(info) {
    if(info.url.indexOf("notifier") + 1){
        return {redirectUrl: "https://domain.null/1.js"};
    }

  },
  {
    urls: [
      "*://domain2.null/*"
    ],
    types: ["script"]
  }, ["blocking"]);
```

I know about **nsIContentPolicy** in firefox, but I don't understand how to use it.

All opinions, advice, and help will be appreciated

### **Answer**

I've determined the problem with the restartless extension. 
To block content we can use nsIContentPolicy as Wladimir said. We also can inject script to page with **windowListener** (aWindow.gBrowser).

For example, this practice works perfectly: https://github.com/jvillalobos/AMO-Admin-Assistant/blob/master/src/bootstrap.js

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think that this can be done without major hacks right now. This is subject of [bug 765934](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=765934) that will add a `redirectTo() method` to the [`nsIHttpChannel` interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIHttpChannel). Once it is implemented code like this should work:

```js
const Ci = Components.interfaces;
const Cu = Components.utils;

Cu.import("resource://gre/modules/Services.jsm");
Cu.import("resource://gre/modules/XPCOMUtils.jsm");

var observer = {
  QueryInterface: XPCOMUtils.generateQI([
    Ci.nsIObserver,
    Ci.nsISupportsWeakReference
  ]),

  observe: function(subject, topic, data)
  {
    if (topic == "http-on-modify-request" &&
        subject instanceof Ci.nsIHttpChannel)
    {
      var uri = subject.URI;
      if (uri.host == "domain2.null" && /\.js(\?|$)/.test(uri.path))
      {
        var redirectUri = Services.io.newURI("https://domain.null/1.js",
                                             null, null);
        subject.redirectTo(redirectUri);
      }
    }
  }
};

Services.obs.addObserver(observer, "http-on-modify-request", true);
```

For reference: [Services.jsm](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript_code_modules/Services.jsm), [XPCOMUtils.jsm](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript_code_modules/XPCOMUtils.jsm), [observer notifications](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Observer_Notifications#HTTP_requests), [nsIHttpChannel](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIHttpChannel), [nsIURI](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIURI)

Comment: Wladimir. Thank you very much for you quickly answer. I'll try to use it. (Additionally thanks for adblockplus)

Comment: Wladimir, can I block loading certain script on webpage by extension?

Comment: @AndreiNikolaev: As I said, `redirectTo()` isn't implemented yet so you cannot use it. However, you can already call [`cancel()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIRequest#cancel%28%29) on a channel instead to stop it. Or you can [use content policies](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10788836/785541), you will get better context information then.

Comment: Oh my God you saved me, It's so hard to work with these API, the documents are not enough I don't really know what to do. I was looking for how to make the redirectURI for hours.