# How to register a content policy (nsIContentPolicy) in a frame script?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, e10s

In e10s we have to register a content policy directly in frame scripts, but I can't find any example that works. I have tested [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10788836/750330) but it only detects when internal resources are loaded, and it gives the following error:

```
NS_ERROR_FACTORY_EXISTS: Component returned failure code: 0xc1f30100 (NS_ERROR_FACTORY_EXISTS) [nsIComponentRegistrar.registerFactory]
```

Does someone knows how to do?